# How do I restore files I deleted by mistake from mercurial during an uncommitted merge?

Tags: mercurial

Stupid mistake on my part, but I did a pull & merge and forgot to do a commit after the merge.

I started working with some files and deleted a folder by mistake.  I tried doing `hg restore` on the files, but I get the error:

```
abort: uncommitted merge with no revision specified
```

and if I try to do `hg ci` I get:

```
abort: cannot commit merge with missing files
```

How can I restore the files so I can commit the merge and continue working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
hg revert <file> -r <specific_revision_to_restore>
```

When there is a merge in progress, Mercurial doesn't know which parent from which to restore the revision.